# R shiny reactive table, render plot can not work

Tags: r, plot, shiny

everyone. I am very new to shiny. I would like to plot a pie chart based on a filter data frame.
Here is my data frame:

```
Duration                Received     Name       Status
1 month                 01/14/2014   Tim        Completed
1 month                 02/12/2014   Chris      Completed
2 months                01/08/2015   Anna       Completed
1 month                 06/25/2014   Jenifer    Completed
2 months                05/14/2015   Ruby       Completed
more than 3 months      11/05/2014   David      Pending
2 months                05/12/2015   Anna       Completed
1 months                03/26/2015   David      Completed
...  ...
```

There may be more than 500 lines in the data frame

First, I tried to subset the data frame by Received Date. And plot the Duration Freq in pie chart. For example, I would like to choose all records after 12/31/2014. So I can select my Received Date. Then, table() Duration column in the subset data frame. Last, plot the pie chart.

My problem is when I change the date Rang of the Received date, my pie plot keep the consistent, never update. Can anyone help me to debug my script and tell me why? Thank you

Here is my code: 
ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ggpie <- function (dat, by, totals) {
    ggplot(dat, aes_string(x=factor(1), y=totals, fill=by)) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity', color='black') +
    guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour=NA))) + 
    coord_polar(theta='y') +
    theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          axis.title=element_blank()) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=cumsum(dat[[totals]]) - dat[[totals]] / 2,       labels=dat[[by]])    
}
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  headerPanel("My App"),  
  sidebarPanel(     
    dateRangeInput("dates", label = h3("Received Date Range"),
               start = "2013-01-01",
               end = as.character(Sys.Date())
    )
  ),   
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("Duration"),
    tableOutput("test")
  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ggpie <- function (dat, by, totals) {
  ggplot(dat, aes_string(x=factor(1), y=totals, fill=by)) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity', color='black') +
    guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour=NA))) + 
    coord_polar(theta='y') +
    theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          #axis.text.x=element_text(colour='black',angle=45, size=10, vjust=0.5),
          axis.title=element_blank()) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=cumsum(dat[[totals]]) - dat[[totals]] / 2, labels=dat[[by]])    
}    
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  #table
  newData= reactive({
    data1 = subset(data, input$dates[1]<=data$Received && data$Received<=input$dates[2])
    data2 = as.data.frame(table(data1$Duration))
  })
  output$test<- renderTable({
    newData()
  })
  output$Duration<-renderPlot({    
    ggpie(newData(), by='Var1', totals="Freq") +
      ggtitle("Duration")+
      scale_fill_discrete(name="Duration")    
  })
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change

```
input$dates[1]<=data$Received && data$Received<=input$dates[2]
```

to

```
input$dates[1]<=data$Received & data$Received<=input$dates[2]
```

`&&` has a different meaning than `&`.  With the former, your aren't doing a comparison along the whole vector `data$Received`.  See `help("&&")`